docker generic docker.sock path (root-less and root-full installation)
- "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro"
# use this for docker-rootles daemon
#- "/run/user/1000/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro"

I have the following lines in my docker-compose.yml. Since traefik needs a docker.sock, I forward it via a docker-socket-proxy in order to minimize security threats.
The problem is that we run this application on machines where docker is installed as root and on machines where docker is not installed as root.
How can I forward docker to my docker socket proxy (using tecnativa/docker-socket-proxy that is) while specifying the path in a generic way, so that it works both on root-less and root-full installations.


Decide on common path for both root docker sock and rootless socket, like /tmp/docker.sock
Create a symlink from that path to root docker or rootless docker socket.
Mount bind that common path.

